# C - define, #include, and redefine

Tags: c

I have a driver which is known to compile on somebody else's machine, however, it's not on mine (a toolchain/compiler difference?).  I'm getting `error: implicit declaration of function '__REG' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]`.  Here's the code which is causing it:

```
enum {
#define __REG(a,b2,b1,c,d,e,f) a,
#include "mycodec-i2c.h"
#undef __REG
};
```

And then later on in the code...

```
static const mycodec_reg_t mycodec_data[]=
{
#define __REG(a,b2,b1,c,d,e,f) c,
#include "mycodec-i2c.h"
#undef __REG
};
```

Is that really legal to do in C?  How do I get around it?

The header file contains a whole bunch of register definitions.

Comment: Are the missing hashes in the "code" snippet a typo?

Comment: Probably we'll also have to know what's in `mycodec-i2c.h`.

Comment: which line was the error coming from?

Comment: that was a typo, I added the missing hashes.

Comment: the error is coming from line mycodec-i2c.h:15:3

Comment: the header file looks like this:
https://code.google.com/p/mydc-proj/source/browse/trunk/linux/target/device/Conexant/DigiColor/common/modules/sound/soc/codecs/cx20709-i2c.h

Comment: Yes; that usage is legal. They are sometimes called x-macros.  If there's an error, you'll have to look at the preprocessed file (`gcc -E`, for example) and deduce from that what the trouble is.

Comment: You are probably including mycodec-i2c.h somewhere where the macro __REG is not defined and this is why you get the error

Comment: gcc should also tell you which line the #include is on for the error.  That will help narrow down the problem.